# Find difference in items of two System.Collections.Generic.Lists

Tags: c#, wpf, list, generics

I have a local copy of `System.Collections.Generic.List` which is populated by a server list of the same type. When  the server list is changed (an item added to list or removed from list), my application gets a notification.

In response to that notification, I want to update my local copy of the list. I dont want to clear the local copy and replace it entirely with the server copy. I want to find the difference and delete the ones that are deleted and add the ones that are added.

What's the best technique to do that?

Comment: What kind of notifications does your client get? Don't key contain some information enough to identify the items in the list to remove them, or add them if they don't exist?

Comment: nope. Would have been a piece of cake if that happens :) I just get a notification saying list has changed

Comment: Since you will have to get a new copy of the list to compare to the old one, what do you hope to gain by only adding and removing the items that changed on the server? Also, can the order of items change too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the notification consists of the whole remote list, you can use Linq's `Except`:

```
List<int> localList = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3};
List<int> remoteList = new List<int>() {1, 2, 4};

var addedItems = remoteList.Except(localList);
var removedItems = localList.Except(remoteList);
```

Comment: I don't see how this would help if he doesn't know what has changed, only that something has changed.

Comment: I assumed that after the notification the OP would fetch the updated list from the server. I guess one could just use it to replace the local list, but the OP explicitly said "I dont want to clear the local copy and replace it entirely with the server copy".

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible to identify each item by some key? If so, then you can hold a dictionary from key to item, and when you get the updated list from the server, you can look for each key in the dictionary and remove/update the corresponding item.

To enable deletion of items from the list, you can copy the entire server data into another dictionary and consult it for each item of the local list.

The complexity of this solution is O(n), as opposed to using `Except` on lists, which would be O(n^2).

Answer (score 1):

it could be done with `LINQ`

```
    string[] names1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"../../../names1.txt");
    string[] names2 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"../../../names2.txt");

    // Create the query. Note that method syntax must be used here.
    IEnumerable<string> differenceQuery =
      names1.Except(names2);

    // Execute the query.
    Console.WriteLine("The following lines are in names1.txt but not names2.txt");
    foreach (string s in differenceQuery)
        Console.WriteLine(s);
```